# How to import a self-signed certificate in Electron Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ssl-certificate

In my Electron application, I will hit a https RESTFUL server which already gave me a crt file. How can I import it in my Electron app and verify if it is safe?

I checked the documentation of Electron. I found the description of certificate object:
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/certificate
But I didn't find any sample of the object data and how to import and verify it.

Now I am using this to bypass it but it's not secure:

```
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, 
callback) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  callback(true);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `importCertificate` on electron's `app`: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appimportcertificateoptions-callback-linux

e.g. if you have the crt file on disk

```
app.importCertificate('/path/my.crt', (result) => {
    if (result == 0) {
        // Success!
    }
});
```

Comment: `importCertificate` is only for Linux. How do I do this on MacOS and Windows –

Comment: The argument is also wrong. This is incorrect. The argument type is an object, not a string.